# Определение настроек браузера у клиента с помощью PHP

Tags: javascript, html, html-form

У меня есть веб-форма, в ней осуществляется проверка полей с помощью JavaScript, необходимо отображать другую форму, в случае когда у пользователя отключена в настройках браузера обработка JS скриптов.

Comment: "необходимо отображать другую форму" - поясните **зачем?**

Comment: дело в том что у меня форма загрузки файлов на сервер, капчу прикрутить геморой составляет, явот и решил просто на клиенте поля сумировать и результат сравнивать с уже сгенерированным результатом в поле, и если чо выбрасывать сообщение либо поле пусто не должно быть либо оно не правильное.

сама форма http://test.afc.ru/exchange/

она успевает послать запрос прежде чем сработает капча

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию показываешь форму когда отключен яваскрипт, при загрузке страницы яваскриптом переключаешь на форму, которую нужно показать когда яваскрипт включен.

P.S. а можно использовать тэг [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Comment: В общем не все так просто :) дело в том что у меня форма загрузки файлов на сервер, капчу прикрутить геморой составляет,  явот и решил просто на клиенте поля сумировать и результат сравнивать с уже сгенерированным результатом в поле, и если чо выбрасывать сообщение либо поле пусто не должно быть либо оно не правильное.

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике формы, так или иначе, вы должны делать проверку на заполненность этого поля. Если оно empty, то верните пользователя назад к форме с сообщением о том, что это поле обязательно.

Comment: При отключенном JS, сразу "послать" сложновато )) И кстати, если юзер отключил JS, то гоняйте туда-сюда - это уже его проблема.

Comment: А не получиться ;D

И вообще - пользователи с выключенным JavaScript'ом еще не вымерли? :D